# Trying to target an <i> tag with specific class names

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have this project im working on, and the roadblock i'm hitting is targeting a specific `<i>` tag within an `<li>` element and matching it with another specific `<i>` element within another `<li>` . This is selecting by clicking the `<li>` element and storing the value in an array, to check for matching `<i>` elements in another `<li>` tag. I don't believe the `$(this).children().innerHTML` is the correct way to target these elements.

[Link to jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/logikevcover/8auxLwtm/1/)

Code below:

```
let cards = [
    "diamond",
    "leaf",
    "cube",
    "bomb",
    "bicycle",
    "anchor",
    "paper-plane-o",
    "bolt",
    "diamond",
    "leaf",
    "cube",
    "bomb",
    "bicycle",
    "anchor",
    "paper-plane-o",
    "bolt"
],
openedCards = [],
$deck = $(".deck"),
$card = (".card"),
$scorePanel = $('#score-panel'),
$moves = $('.moves'),
$rating = $("i"),
$restart = $(".restart"),
delay = 500,
match = 0,
moves = 0,
amountOfCards = cards.length / 2,
threeStars = amountOfCards + 2,
twoStars = amountOfCards + 6,
oneStar = amountOfCards + 10;


// Shuffle function
function shuffle(array) {
    let currentIndex = array.length,
        temporaryValue, randomIndex;

    while (currentIndex !== 0) {
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;
        temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
        array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
        array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }

    return array;
}

// Create the new Game

function newBoard() {
    let shuffledCards = shuffle(cards);
    $deck.empty();
    match = 0;
    moves = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        $deck.append($('<li class="card"><i class="fa fa-' + cards[i] 
+ '"></i></li>'))
    }
    cardClickListener();
};

let cardClickListener = function() {
    $deck.find('.card:not(".match, .open")').on("click", function() {
        let $this = $(this);
        let card = $this.children().innerHTML;
        $this.addClass("open show");
        openedCards.push(card);
        console.log(openedCards);

        if (openedCards.length > 1) {
             if (card === openedCards[0]) {
                 $deck.find('.open').addClass('match');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $deck.find('.match').removeClass('open show');
                }, delay);
            }   
        }
    });
};

newBoard();
```

Comment: Post the HTML and a working demo, please.

Comment: Did you try something like: `$(this).find("i.myClassName")`?

Comment: Added jsfiddle to post. and let me try spencer

Answer (score 0):

Ok i figured it out. I had to target my specific card with

`let card = $(this).children("i").attr("class");`

at that point I was able to push the card variable storing the value into my empty array.